# Communications with RTL text in "Jobs" aren't rendered correctly

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, rtl

I just received a communication from the Jobs module and since I live in Israel it was written in Hebrew and had three problems with it.
[image: Screenshot of part of the message]

1. The whole thing is aligned to the left rather than to the right.
2. When mixing RTL and LTR text (C++ in this case) the sentence gets mangled (not only is C++ converted to, the arguably more correct, ++C, it's at the beginning of the sentence (right) rather than at its end(left))
3. Punctuation is also placed in the wrong place (right rather than left).

Comment: RTL seems to be a problem in many places on Stack Exchange. I've posted about this with regards to the Android app, and recently found another situation where a rtl username messed up the layout.

Comment: @m69 yeah, I later saw this when creating the [tag:rtl] tag. Since this is an English site the problem isn't very pronounced, I've been using stackoverflow for over seven years and this is the first I came across this problem.

Comment: And if you think that `++C` looks weird, adding an `@rtl_username` to an English comment changes `:-)` into `(-:` in the Android app.

Comment: @m69 not `)-:`?

Comment: @Motti what communication was it that you received? Was this a particular job listing, was it in an email, etc?

Comment: @DeanWard this was a message I got via the [**jobs** portion of SO](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox). If you want more specifics I suggest you contact me personally.